# do lambdas nested in a method expression run even after the method returns a value?

Tags: java, lambda

I've been learning java using the book "Core java I" by Cay_S._Horstmann, and during my reading session I've stumbled upon a statement that I didn't quite understand

"the code of the lambda expression may run long after the call to repeatMessage has returned and the parameter variables are gone"

```
public static void repeatMessage(String text, int delay)
{
    ActionListener listener = event ->
    {
        System.out.println(text);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    };
    new Timer(delay, listener);
}
```

as far as my short experience of programming goes, I'm pretty sure that all the methods after they have been used will be erased with their local variables from the stack for good (better memory management), so why isn't it the case with nested lambda expressions especially when the sole reason for their existence is to use one block of code only once and then forget about it? am I missing something?

Comment: Yes. A [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#Timer-int-java.awt.event.ActionListener-) starts a new thread and the listener is invoked by that thread every `delay` period.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the fact that the ActionListener is a lambda or a nested lambda; it's just the fact that a method in one thread can be run (and continue running) even after the method which *started* the thread has finished.

Comment: It acts like a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)). Basically the reference to `text` gets copied.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, such lambdas can be passed around as normal objects and will continue working long after the  method has returned. If that wasn't the case, then their usefulness would be significantly diminished.

Internally the lambda will create local copies of any parameter or local variable values that it uses (but this is transparent to you). This way it can still execute when the method invocation during which it was created has finished.

Comment: can you please elaborate more when you replied with " then their usefulness would be significantly diminished." thanks!

Comment: @Naito: I don't really know what to elaborate on that. All but the most trivial use cases depend on the fact that they can be passed around and treated like normal objects. If their usefulness ended at the point of method return then that would be severely limited. One example for this is simple event listeners: if the event listener only works as long as the method that sets up the event listener is running, then it's basically pointless.